# C++, sort through array of numbers to find uniqueness

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, unique

Say I have an array of 4 different numbers.

int numbers[4] = {50234, 50356, 50454, 50934};

How do you make a nested for loop in C++ to sort through these numbers from back to front in order to identify the required amount of digits needed for uniqueness?

From the example you can tell that you'll need 3 digits from the back to make sure no numbers contain similar tails of numbers. 50234, 50934 = 3 digits to have them unique = 502 and 509 respectively.

What would the for loop look like to go through each of these numbers one by one, number by number, and sort out identical numbers to reach an output of 3?

It would go like this:

4

6 - discard this number, it's not identical

4

4

Then:

3

5 - discard this number

3

Then:

2

9 Hurray! No similar numbers anymore, print out 3 being the answer.

I'm stumped and can't figure it out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Don't you really need to check the whole number?  `502123456789` and `503123456789` have a lot of the same digits from the back but they are different numbers.

Comment: no logic for illogic

Comment: I'm new to C++ and just a beginner with it. I do not need to check the whole number. I just want it to go through every position of the number from the back to the front. It can discard the numbers where no number is similar, and stop once it reaches a position in the numbers where no number is similar. Does that make sense? :/

Comment: I have tried a nested for loop with 3 loops in it. First one going through the length of the numbers (so 5), the next one going through the amount of numbers (which is 4), and the last loop comparing each number with the next to see if the numbers happen to be identical. Did not work out for me..

Comment: Seeing that code would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Say you start with

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    const std::vector<int> numbers{50234, 50356, 50454, 50934};
```

You can transform it into a vector of strings:

```
    std::vector<std::string> string_numbers;
    std::for_each(std::begin(numbers), std::end(numbers), [&](int n){ string_numbers.push_back(std::to_string(n)); });
```

Now we'll check the number of digits required, starting at 1:

```
    size_t digits = 1;
    while(true) {
```

At each iteration, we'll create an `unordered_set`

```
        std::unordered_set<std::string> partials;
```

For each number, we'll attempt to place `digits` digits of it into the set:

```
        for(const auto &s: string_numbers) {
            if(s.size() <= digits) {
                std::cout << "not unique" << std::endl;
                return 0;
            } 
            partials.insert(s.substr(0, digits));
        }
```

If the size of the set is the size of the vector, we're done:

```
        if(partials.size() == numbers.size()) {
                std::cout << digits << " required" << std::endl;
                return 0;
            }
```

Otherwise, we need to increase the number of digits:

```
        ++digits;
    }
}
```

---

Full code:

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    const std::vector<int> numbers{50234, 50356, 50454, 50934};

    std::vector<std::string> string_numbers;
    std::for_each(std::begin(numbers), std::end(numbers), [&](int n){ string_numbers.push_back(std::to_string(n)); });

    size_t digits = 1;
    while(true) {
        std::unordered_set<std::string> partials;
        for(const auto &s: string_numbers) {
            if(s.size() <= digits) {
                std::cout << "not unique" << std::endl;
                return 0;
            } 
            partials.insert(s.substr(0, digits));
        }
        if(partials.size() == numbers.size()) {
                std::cout << digits << " required" << std::endl;
                return 0;
            }
        ++digits;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Ami, just wanted to say thank you for your solution here. I am still very new to c++ and this is beyond a level I can comprehend, but it let me to the answer I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to sort numbers so use one of sort algorithms let's say bubble sort. then check for uniqueness and store the unique values in a new array then print them:

we make our code for understanding and practice but in a real program we use libraries they are too much powerful and quick:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;



int main()
{

    int numbers[4] = {50234, 50356, 50454, 50934};
//  int numbers[4] = {50234, 50356, 50454, 50356};

    for(int i(0); i < 4; i++)
    {
        for(int j(i + 1); j < 4; j++)
        {
            if(numbers[i] > numbers[j])
            {
                numbers[i] ^= numbers[j];
                numbers[j] ^= numbers[i];
                numbers[i] ^= numbers[j];
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        cout << numbers[i] << ", ";

    int  nUniq = 0;
    bool isUniq = true;

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        isUniq = true;

        for(int j(i + 1); j < 4; j++)
        {
            if(numbers[i] == numbers[j])
            {
                isUniq = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(isUniq)
            nUniq++;
    }

    cout << nUniq << endl;

    int* ptrUniq = new int[nUniq];
    int k = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        isUniq = true;

        for(int j(i + 1); j < 4; j++)
        {
            if(numbers[i] == numbers[j])
            {
                isUniq = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(isUniq)
        {
            ptrUniq[k] = numbers[i];
            k++;
        }
    }

    cout << "\nhere are uniq values:\n\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < nUniq; i++)
        cout << ptrUniq[i] << ", ";

    delete[] ptrUniq;
    ptrUniq = NULL;


    cout << endl << endl;
    return 0;
}
```